# About $(x^p-1)^2 = 4^cy^p$

Tags: number-theory

I need to prove that $(x^p-1)^2 = 4^cy^p$ has no integer solutions, $x,c,y$ are positive integers, $p$ is prime greater than $2$.
It looks obvious to me but cannot form it in a mathematical way. 
I transformed the equation to $x^p(x^2-2)+1$ surely there is something with the $+1$ .
Can you please help?

Comment: You are here for a month now. Have a look at  [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so that you can do some formatting yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample: $x=3$, $y=2$, $c=2$, $p=2$, gives $(3^2-1)^2=64=4^2\,2^2$.

For $p$ odd, there are no solutions since if $y$ has a prime $q$ that occurs an odd number of times then it would occur an odd number on the right-hand side but an even number on the left.

The case when $p\ge3$ odd and $y=z^2$ gives $x^p-2^cz^p=1$. This is a not a trivial problem at all. For $c=1$, it is covered by the main theorem of this paper by [Henri Darmon and Loic Merel](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Research/18.Merel/paper.pdf) and is related to the Fermat-Wiles theorem.

Comment: $y$ could be a square?

Comment: MMS, you are right, I am interested in p>2.  But as Marks says y can be a square so in this case  the power of its q is even.